# How to tune the polling period of NAPI?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-device-driver

I can understand that NAPI in Linux will change from interrupt to poll mode to handle the high packet rate.

NAPI uses weight to decide how many packets to process in each poll period; It also makes sure that the packet handling in each poll period is less than one jiffies.

However, I couldn't find in anywhere (google) what is the poll period of NAPI? Can we change the poll period to any value we want?

Thank you very much for any of your help!

---

From what I observe, it seems that NAPI's poll period is 2 second, but I want to make sure my observation is correct.

Comment: Poll period?  I thought that NAPI reverts back to interrupt mode once the receive queue is empty (or the budget cannot be consumed by the driver).  There is no periodic timer associated with NAPI polling.

Comment: I see... If it is the case, it means that my observation is due to some service that is invoked every 2 seconds and uses the network. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

NAPI packet processing is controlled in two ways:

1. With the `netdev_budget` which is the total number of packets that can be processed. This can be tuned by setting the `net.core.netdev_budget` sysctl.
2. On Linux 4.12+, with  `netdev_budget_usecs` which is the total time in microseconds that can be spent processing packets. The corresponding sysctl parameter is  `net.core.netdev_budget_usecs`.
   On Linux < 4.12, the sysctl does not exist and this value is hardcoded to 2 jiffies. It cannot be tuned.

I wrote a [detailed blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) describing the Linux network stack in detail that may interest you and [this section](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/#netrxaction-processing-loop) shows the code for the NAPI processing loop where the hardcoded timeout can be found.

Comment: Hi, I have been following your blog post for a quite of bit of time now. That's a very illustrative blog post. Thanks for that. I have a query regarding the scheduling of NAPI. Is it possible to schedule the NAPI poll to execute at a certain point of time? for example every 500ms (without any interrupts being raised). I saw a timer field in NAPI struct(http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L306).  Not sure if it is the field that I am looking for. will try it though. Any information on this would be helpful. Thank you !

Comment: @cooshal Did you get time to experiment on the timer based NAPI approach ? Any findings to share ?